# Why Math.Round(Math.Log(1, 2) + 0.5) equals zero?

Tags: c#, double

I have following code:

```cs
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{Math.Round(0.5)} = round(0.5)");
        Console.WriteLine($"{ToBinaryString(0.5)} = binary 0.5");
        
        Console.WriteLine();
        
        Console.WriteLine($"{Math.Log(1, 2)} = log2(1)");
        Console.WriteLine($"{ToBinaryString(Math.Log(1, 2))} = binary log2(1)");
        
        Console.WriteLine();
        
        Console.WriteLine($"{Math.Round(Math.Log(1, 2) + 0.5)} = round(log2(1) + 0.5)");
        Console.WriteLine($"{ToBinaryString(Math.Log(1, 2) + 0.5)} = binary log2(1) + 0.5");
        
        Console.WriteLine();
        
        Console.WriteLine($"{Math.Round(0.0 + 0.5)} = round(0.0 + 0.5");
        Console.WriteLine($"{ToBinaryString(0.0 + 0.5)} = binary 0.0 + 0.5");
        
        Console.WriteLine();
        
        Console.WriteLine($"{Math.Log(1, 2) + 0.5 == 0.5} = Math.Log(1, 2) + 0.5 == 0.5");
        Console.WriteLine($"{Math.Log(1, 2) == 0.0} = Math.Log(1, 2) == 0.0");
    }
    
    static string ToBinaryString(double value)
    {
        const int bitCount = sizeof(double) * 8;
        long intValue = System.BitConverter.ToInt64(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), 0);
        return Convert.ToString(intValue, 2).PadLeft(bitCount, '0');
    }
```

The output is:

```
1 = round(0.5)
0011111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 = binary 0.5

0 = log2(1)
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 = binary log2(1)

0 = round(log2(1) + 0.5) // ???? Why ????
0011111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 = binary log2(1) + 0.5

1 = round(0.0 + 0.5
0011111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 = binary 0.0 + 0.5

True = Math.Log(1, 2) + 0.5 == 0.5
True = Math.Log(1, 2) == 0.0
```

According the output, I can say, that `Math.Log(1, 2)` is a exactly `0` and  `Math.Log(1, 2) + 0.5` is exactly `0.5`. I think so, because their representations in memory are equal. So precision of `double` type affects nothing in this case. Fix me if I wrong.

But `Math.Round(Math.Log(1, 2) + 0.5)` doesn't equal  `Math.Round(0.5)` or `Math.Round(0.0 + 0.5)`. How it could be explained?

Comment: `Math.Round(Math.Log(1, 2) + 0.5)` is equal `Math.Round(0.5)`.How do you say they are not equal?

Comment: Can't replicate: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CTcE8X

Comment: I can replicate here https://www.programiz.com/csharp-programming/online-compiler/

Comment: What framework version and OS are you using?

Comment: @GuruStron windows 10 and .NET 6.0

Comment: Can't repro on mine. But in general this can be expected - see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-7.0#rounding-and-precision)

Comment: @GuruStron I agree. It can be expected, that `Math.Round(Math.Log(1,2) + 0.5)` is `0`. I even can guess, that it is depends on framework and language version. But the fact is that `Math.Round(Math.Log(1,2) + 0.5)` != `Math.Round(0.5)` is not expected for me.

Comment: `Math.Round(0.5)` should be `0` -- `Math.Round` uses midpoint rounding by default, which means that midpoints get rounded to the nearest even number. It looks like your online compiler uses Roslyn 3.9.0, whereas sharplab and dotnetfiddle use 4.4.0, so something changed recently. This is to do with basic math operations being evaluated at JIT-time I think, still investigating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in mono, see [mono/mono#20449](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/20449).

The JIT is able to do constant folding for simple math operations. For example, if you write `Math.Round(0.5)`, the JIT spots that this is a constant operation with the value `0`, and just replaces the whole operation with `0`.

When you have a more complex operation, such as `Math.Round(Math.Log(1, 2) + 0.5)`, the mono JIT isn't able to work out that this is a constant, and instead emits code to run the log and round operations at runtime. (It looks like the normal .NET JIT is able to constant fold this particular expression however, interestingly).

In this particular case, there was a bug in the mono JIT when it did this specific constant fold, and it replaced the `Math.Round(0.5)` with `1` instead of `0`. This was fixed in 2020, but it looks like programiz is using an old version of mono.

---

I started by looking at the differences between sharplab/dotnetfiddle and the programiz online compiler you were using. It's pretty clear that programiz is using mono, as the first line of output is (e.g.):

> mono /tmp/KCimGB9o1m.exe

I know that sharplab and dotnetfiddle don't use Mono, and you can test this with `Console.WriteLine(Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime") != null);`.

The difference between `Math.Round(0.5)` and `Math.Round(<expression> + 0.5)` indicated that it was probably to do with constant folding, and the difference with mono probably meant a JIT issue. A [quick search](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues?q=math.round) of the dotnet/runtime repo for `Math.Round` revealed the issue on the first page.